# Complex models with json_serializable - List<objects> not converting to map

Tags: flutter, dart, serializable

**UPDATE**
I have built a small sample and will add all code to this post.  I have to believe there is an answer/explanation to this and am hoping someone can educate me on what I'm missing.  Class fields that are type object are not getting converted and I do not understand why.

**Here are the model classes I'm working with.**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'parent.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Parent {
  int id;
  final String name;
  final int age;
  List<Child> children;
  Job job;

  Parent({this.name, this.age, this.children, this.job});

  factory Parent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ParentFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ParentToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Child{
  int id;
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Child({this.name, this.age});

  factory Child.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ChildFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ChildToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Job{
  int id;
  String title;

  Job({this.title});

  factory Job.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$JobFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$JobToJson(this);
}
```

**Here is the .g generated file for these classes**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'parent.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Parent _$ParentFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Parent(
    name: json['name'] as String,
    age: json['age'] as int,
    children: (json['children'] as List)
        ?.map(
            (e) => e == null ? null : Child.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
    job: json['job'] == null
        ? null
        : Job.fromJson(json['job'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  )..id = json['id'] as int;
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ParentToJson(Parent instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'name': instance.name,
      'age': instance.age,
      'children': instance.children,
      'job': instance.job,
    };

Child _$ChildFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Child(
    name: json['name'] as String,
    age: json['age'] as int,
  )..id = json['id'] as int;
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ChildToJson(Child instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'name': instance.name,
      'age': instance.age,
    };

Job _$JobFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Job(
    title: json['title'] as String,
  )..id = json['id'] as int;
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$JobToJson(Job instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'title': instance.title,
    };
```

**Here is the DAO class for the parent class**

```
import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';

import 'package:json_serial_test/services/app_database.dart';
import 'package:json_serial_test/models/parent.dart';

class ParentDao {
  static const String PARENT_STORE_NAME = 'parents';
  // A Store with int keys and Map<String, dynamic> values.
  // This Store acts like a persistent map, values of which are Parent objects converted to Map
  final _parentStore = intMapStoreFactory.store(PARENT_STORE_NAME);

  // Private getter to shorten the amount of code needed to get the
  // singleton instance of an opened database.
  Future<Database> get _db async => await AppDatabase.instance.database;

  Future insert(Parent parent) async {
    await _parentStore.add(await _db, parent.toJson());
  }

  Future update(Parent parent) async {
    // For filtering by key (ID), RegEx, greater than, and many other criteria,
    // we use a Finder.
    final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.byKey(parent.id));
    await _parentStore.update(
      await _db,
      parent.toJson(),
      finder: finder,
    );
  }

  Future deleteAll() async {
    await _parentStore.delete(await _db);
  }

  Future delete(Parent parent) async {
    final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.byKey(parent.id));
    await _parentStore.delete(
      await _db,
      finder: finder,
    );
  }

  Future<List<Parent>> getAllSortedByName() async {
    // Finder object can also sort data.
    final finder = Finder(sortOrders: [
      SortOrder('name'),
    ]);

    final recordSnapshots = await _parentStore.find(
      await _db,
      finder: finder,
    );

    // Making a List<Parent> out of List<RecordSnapshot>
    return recordSnapshots.map((snapshot) {
      final parent = Parent.fromJson(snapshot.value);
      // An ID is a key of a record from the database.
      parent.id = snapshot.key;
      return parent;
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

**Here is my test**

```
// Setup
          final k1 = Child(name: 'Billy', age: 10);
          final k2 = Child(name: 'Jannet', age: 9);
          final job = Job(title: 'Cook');
          final List<Child> kids = [k1, k2];

          final dad = Parent(name: 'Dave', age: 52, job: job, children: kids);

          await pDao.insert(dad);

          List<Parent> dadsInDb = await pDao.getAllSortedByName();

          print('Dads from DB: ${dadsInDb.toString()}');
```

Upon trying to perform an insert of a Parent into my sembast DB, this is the error that shows up.

```
E/flutter (12986): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): value Instance of 'Child' unsupported type Child E/flutter (12986): #0      cloneValue (package:sembast/src/utils.dart:191:3) E/flutter (12986): #1      cloneValue.<anonymous closure> (package:sembast/src/utils.dart:177:33) E/flutter (12986): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:29) E/flutter (12986): #3      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:221:19) E/flutter (12986): #4      cloneValue (package:sembast/src/utils.dart:177:52) E/flutter (12986): #5      cloneValue.<anonymous closure> (package:sembast/src/utils.dart:174:49) E/flutter (12986): #6      MapMixin.map (dart:collection/maps.dart:165:28) E/flutter (12986): #7  cloneValue (package:sembast/src/utils.dart:173:18) E/flutter (12986):
#8      SembastStore.txnPutSync (package:sembast/src/store_impl.dart:133:15) E/flutter (12986): #9     SembastStore.txnAdd (package:sembast/src/store_impl.dart:117:11) E/flutter (12986): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (12986): #10    StoreRefMixin.add.<anonymous closure> (package:sembast/src/store_ref_impl.dart:75:12) E/flutter (12986): #11 SembastDatabase.inTransaction.<anonymous closure> (package:sembast/src/database_impl.dart:1238:34) E/flutter (12986):
#12     SembastDatabase.transaction.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:sembast/src/database_impl.dart:1090:59) E/flutter (12986): #13     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31) E/flutter (12986): #14     SembastDatabase.transaction.<anonymous closure> (package:sembast/src/database_impl.dart:1090:26) E/flutter (12986): #15     BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:32:26) E/flutter (12986):
#16     SembastDatabase.transaction (package:sembast/src/database_impl.dart:1073:38) E/flutter (12986):
#17     SembastDatabase.inTransaction (package:sembast/src/database_impl.dart:1238:7) E/flutter (12986): #18 StoreRefMixin.add (package:sembast/src/store_ref_impl.dart:72:25) E/flutter (12986): #19     ParentDao.insert (package:json_serial_test/data/parent_dao.dart:17:24) E/flutter (12986): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (12986): #20    
_MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:json_serial_test/main.dart:120:22) E/flutter (12986): #21    
_InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14) E/flutter (12986):
#22     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36) E/flutter (12986):
#23     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24) E/flutter (12986): #24     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11) E/flutter (12986): #25  BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5) E/flutter (12986): #26   BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7) E/flutter (12986): #27   GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27) E/flutter (12986):
#28     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20) E/flutter (12986):
#29     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22) E/flutter (12986):
#30     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7) E/flutter (12986):
#31     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7) E/flutter (12986):
#32     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7) E/flutter (12986):
#33     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13) E/flutter (12986): #34     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19) E/flutter (12986): #35     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7) E/flutter (12986): #36     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10) E/flutter (12986): #37    
_dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5) E/flutter (12986):
```

If someone could please assist me in showing what I've missed, done incorrectly, I would greatly appreciate it.

**ORIGINAL POST**
**==============**
Should `json_serializable` convert ALL of a class to JSON, or are there limitations that I am hitting?

I have decided to try and resolve a slew of issues I've caused myself by using `json_serializable` to create the toJson and fromJson methods needed for working with a `NoSQL DB`.

If I create a class which includes a field that is a `List<Ojb>`, the generated code seems to result in JSON for each field of the class but fails to do so for the objects in the list.

Simple example

```
class Parent {
  final int age;
  final String name;
  List<Child> children;

  Parent({this.age, this.name, this.children});

}

class Child {
  final int age;
  final String name;

  Child({this.age, this.name});
}
```

When I use json_serializable, which seems to work beautifully, I get my toJson and fromJson methods for the above mentioned classes.  At first glance, everything looks perfect.

When I attempt to insert a Parent (containing children) into my NoSQL DB, the insert fails to say that the type (referencing the Child object) is not supported - True statement, have no issues with that.

When I step through this via the debugger, here is what I am seeing.

`Parent` is converted to map
age shows up as key with its value
the name shows up as key with its value

Up to this point, I can see that everything is a map[.. and all looks great

Then we get to the list of Child objects.

This part is not converted to a map but still exists as a list of Child objects, hence the failure of the insert.

Both classes have the `jsonSerializable` annotation
Both classes are generating the expected code (part of), classes

Everything works perfectly as long as I don't try to use a `List<myObject>` in one of my classes.

The entire reason one would use a package like json_serializable is to rely on the code that is automatically generated and not have to build it myself.  I don't want to have to manually update automatically generated code to resolve this, which is why I have not pasted in the code.  If that's the answer, then I'll take a different route.

**My question is... is there some configuration that I am missing or possibly doing incorrectly that would allow ALL items within the class to be converted to map/json, even when the fields of a class are not just simple int and string types.  I would expect that I could have a class which includes primitives, along with objects, Lists of objects, etc. and everything should generate correctly, or no?**

Comment: you must you generatetoJson in build.yaml for json serialization

Comment: Hi Ayush, can you explain a further on what you mean?  I do realize I can configure the serializable using the build configuration pubspec.yaml file, but how does this impact the way in which the files are generated?

Comment: You did a large edit. Can you confirm that it does not change the question? I.e. that your edit does not invalidate existing answers? I ask because of the size of the edit and the fact that you already have accepted an answer....

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After many trials and rebuilds, I have resolved this issue and everything appears to be working now with my Sembast DB using json_serializable for my model classes.  Possibly there were other factors that contributed to my success, but I think the main difference was adding the following parameter to the JSONSerializable annotation of the Parent class.

explicitToJson: true

Here is the code, in the event it helps somebody else out there.

The full explanation you can find here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Parent {
  int id;
  final String name;
  final int age;
  List<Child> children;
  Job job;

  Parent({this.name, this.age, this.children, this.job});

  factory Parent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ParentFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ParentToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: For anyone running into this issue using freezed - see https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/86#issuecomment-593936459

Comment: Thanks! After several hours trying to understand what was wrong with my code, you saved me! Same scenario, complex model with lists. I think this should be actually marked as a bug in the json_serializable plugin, not sure why had to add the `explicitToJson: true` flag