# Using dart's json_serializable package with custom properties

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, json-serializable

### Background

I'm trying to use the dart `json_serializable` package to encode/decode a custom type I'm writing/reading with Google Cloud Firestore, and I'm having an issue with the custom type having properties that are also custom types.

I'm storing a Habit which has two custom properties:
`HabitFrequency` is a combination of an integer, and an enum frequencyType that I want to store together as a map in Firestore.

`HabitCompletion` is a list of the type `HabitCompletion`, which contains a date, completion status, and an optional string value/numeric value. I want this to be stored as an array of maps.

### Issue

Whenever I try to save, I get this error:

`[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'HabitFrequency'`

I have the top-level class and both custom classes used as properties (`HabitFrequency` and `HabitCompletion`) listed as JsonSerializable, and they have the appropriate `fromJson`/`toJson` methods specified.

### Question

Is there a different way I need to set these up before I run build_runner build to generate the right code to serialize these properly?

### Code Examples

Here is my top-level class:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Habit {
  String? id;
  String title;
  @JsonKey(name: 'frequency')
  HabitFrequency frequency;
  List<HabitCompletion>? completions;

  Habit({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.frequency,
    this.completions,
  });

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory Habit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$HabitFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonToJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$HabitToJson(this);
  }
}
```

The Habit Frequency:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class HabitFrequency {
  int amount;
  HabitFrequencyType frequencyType;

  HabitFrequency(this.amount, this.frequencyType);

  /// Connect the generated [_$HabitFrequencyFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory HabitFrequency.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$HabitFrequencyFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$HabitFrequencyToJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$HabitFrequencyToJson(this);
}
```

And the Habit completion:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class HabitCompletion {
  DateTime timestamp;
  bool completion;
  String? stringValue;
  double? numericValue;

  HabitCompletion(
      {required this.timestamp,
      required this.completion,
      this.stringValue,
      this.numericValue});

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory HabitCompletion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$HabitCompletionFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonToJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$HabitCompletionToJson(this);
}
```

They each have one property that is just a simple enumeration.

If you want to see more of the code, here's a  [gist](https://gist.github.com/Quesajo17/207e4307ee903999075f0270d1ba265d) containing the file for this type (and the custom types used for the properties in questions), as well as the auto-generated code coming from json_serializable.

Comment: Do you have toJson and fromJson also under enums? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035817/how-to-manage-serialize-deserialize-an-enum-property-with-dart-flutter-to-fi

Comment: I don't think it's necessary with this. When I look at the generated code, there is an enum map automatically created for those enums (they are defined in the same file). It looks like those are already specified. I tested with one enum without the custom type and it looks like the enum mapped to string just fine.

Comment: Voting to close this question - this other question has exactly the same issue and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595703/complex-models-with-json-serializable-listobjects-not-converting-to-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be resolved by setting `explicitToJson` on the JsonSerializable annotation for the Habit class as mentioned in your [gist](https://gist.github.com/Quesajo17/207e4307ee903999075f0270d1ba265d?permalink_comment_id=4313012#gistcomment-4313012)

```dart
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Habit{
....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u should be getting syntax as some properties are not defined but u are using them in the constructor?

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Habit {
  String? id;
  String title;
  @JsonKey(name: 'frequency')
  HabitFrequency frequency;
  List<HabitCompletion>? completions;

  Habit({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    // not defined??????
    this.description,
    // not defined?????? //etc...
    required this.userId,
    this.attachedDashboardId,
    this.attachedGoalId,
    required this.startDate,
    this.endDate,
    this.isActive = true,
    this.positivity = HabitPositivity.positive,
    this.frequency,
    this.completions,
  });

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory Habit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$HabitFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonToJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$HabitToJson(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoops - this was a half-updated code snippet - I removed some of the properties that were not relevant to this question for readability but missed that in the constructor. Updating.

Comment: @CharliePage would suggest to create a gist so we can get a better visibility

Comment: What is a gist?

Comment: can read more about gist https://docs.github.com/en/rest/gists

Comment: Cool, learned something new! Thanks Afzal. I just created one.